# Is there any sublimetext2 like autopreview available to FuzzyFinder or any other VIM file opening plugin?

Tags: vim, fuzzyfinder

In SublimeText when using the file opener command, file names that are hovered over are auto previewed in the background.  Is there any such file opener / add-on available to VIM that implements this?

Comment: you mean the files content is previewed? I want to add that it is quite uncommon for vim users to use the mouse especially when typing a file name or something the like. It would be more apt to a plugin like nerdtree, but i don't know if it has already been written.

Comment: What would be the point of such a weird feature?

Comment: Not sure why you guys think this is weird.. It's one of the most popular features of SublimeText and it is all keyboard driven.. When a dropdown of all the 'searched' files is key'd through.. whatever the currently highlighted file is, the file is previewed in the open buffer.  It gives you a really nice visual as you are key'ing through of what you are looking at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest thing I can think of is NerdTree's preview functionality.

In NerdTree:

- Use `j`,`k` to move the cursor over a filename
- Press `go` to preview it - this leaves the cursor in NerdTree
- The next file you open will be opened in the same "preview" buffer

This way, pressing `jgo` repeatedly gives you a quick way to preview each file.